# Using Elements of a javapanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a main `JFrame` which consists of 3 small `JPanel` which are switched on the basis of selection by the user.

The problem is that I have to save the data inserted into `JPanel` into the database but I am unable to access the elements of the `JPanel` directly. So how do I accept those.

The entry in DB is done when the ACCEPT button is clicked in the main frame.
Please help

```
if(Selected==Credit Card){
    Select Credit Card Panel;
    }
if(Selected==Debit Card){
    Select Debit Card Panel;
    }
if(Selected==Cash on Delivery){
    Select Cash on Delivery Panel;
    }



onAccept(){
    if(Selected==Credit Card){
get data from Credit Card panel and store in Database; (variables like cc number, cvv)
}

if(Selected==Debit Card){
get data from Debit Card panel and store in Database;
}

if(Selected==Cash on Delivery){
get data from Cash on Delivery Card panel and store in Database;
}
    }
```

Comment: To avoid complete guesswork here, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have each of your 3 panels implement the same interface:

```
public interface DataStorer {
    public void storeDataInDatabase();
}
```

Then, when the accept button is clicked, call this:

```
DataStorer selectedPanel = (DataStorer) theDisplayedPanel;
selectedPanel.storeDataInDatabase();
```

Comment: is there no way by which I can directly access the elements?

Comment: Yes there is. Add a method in the panels which returns the data.